# Docker compose vs run with SQL Server container

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I'd like to run SQL Server in a docker container. From what I've googled, this should work:

```
docker run --name sqlserver -p 1433:1433 -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -e SA_PASSWORD=strong@Password123 -d --rm microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest tail -f /dev/null
```

When run this way, docker spins up a container and everything looks OK, but its not! When I try and connect to it, I get errors. Connecting via bash:

```
sudo docker exec -it sqlserver "bash"
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "strong@Password123"
```

gives these errors:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
```

I'm pretty sure this is because the database server isn't actually running.

My second test involved spinning up the server using docker-compose. Contents of the compose file:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  sqlserver:
    container_name: sqlserver
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "strong@Password123"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

then:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

When run this way I can exec into the container OK and hit the SQL prompt. Success! However my preference is to run the server/container using one line, as its a step in a Jenkins build and I don't want it to get too complicated.

Can anyone explain what's going on here and/or point me in the right direction? Why does `docker-compose` work for this while `run` doesn't?

Comment: Your `docker run` command is telling it to run `tail -f /dev/null` instead of running a database.  The Docker Compose equivalent would be a `command:`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. I worked it out. The sql server SA password requirements defined by Microsoft are that the password contains characters from three of the following four categories:

- Latin uppercase letters (A through Z)
- Latin lowercase letters (a through z)
- Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
- Non-alphanumeric characters such as: exclamation point (!), dollar
  sign ($), number sign (#), or percent (%).

While my original password meets these requirements, it turns out that this is actually not enough. When I used the following password `SecretP@55w0rd` instead of the original, the `docker run` command keeps the server up. Thanks Microsoft for using a undocumented password complexity feature!

For some reason when you run the server using `docker compose` this password requirement isn't as strict.